# How to let cron job pull the docker image once after deploying?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cron, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a dozen of cron jobs on GKE. My docker registry is down. The status of these cron jobs becomes: `ImagePullBackOff`

My thinking is, the cron jobs should pull the docker image once after deploying and use the cached/local docker image.

Shouldn't pull the docker image every time from remote docker registry when the cron job creates a new pod. It's a waste, because the docker image doesn't change (I mean the application code of cron job).

So, is there a way to do this?

Purpose: if can do this, my cron jobs will always running using local docker image before next deploying, even if docker registry is down.

Comment: the default `imagePullPolicy` is IfNotPresent. are you sure that it's not set in your case to always?

Comment: @Amityo  I don't set `imagePullPolicy`

Comment: @Amityo I think I found the issue. In my local yaml file, I don't set `imagePullPolicy `. But after I deployed to GKE, and check the yaml file in gcloud console, I found `imagePullPolicy` is be set `Always`. Why?

Comment: not sure why, but I see that @Hanx answered the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use one of the "**Container Images" properties** mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images).

Please setup in your deployment: `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`.

Note:

> if imagePullPolicy is omitted and either the image tag is :latest or it is omitted: Always is applied.

Please verify your deployment settings and verify also if docker images are present on the machine.

Comment: Thanks. You saved me. That's the reason. I omit `imagePullPolicy` in my local yaml file.
So it is set to `Always` after I deployed to GKE.